# How use sqlcipher in android native NDK using JNI (Java Native interface)

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, sqlcipher

I am using this method  of sqlcipher to create encrypted sqlite database in my android studio project by java code.

```
package net.sqlcipher.database;
.
.
public static SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(File file, String password, CursorFactory factory)
```

the version of sqlcipher is 4.4.3

Everything is okay, but some part of my app is written by native coed (NDK) and I need to open and query encrypted DB.
I do not know how work with this DB by native code?
the previous **sqlite3_exec** function return errMsg that **file is not a database**.
in fact I do not find the header to include in native code.

Comment: compile sqlcipher yourself and use that in native code?

Comment: tanks , but i am not familiar with c programming please tell me more details .
I found this link [link](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/introduction/)
But i can not understand witch command should use on witch files and directory .
i just know i need a Header file like sqlite3.h to call 
int sqlite3_key(sqlite3 *db, const void *pKey, int nKey);

Comment: If you're not familiar with C, the JNI will be very painful.